# inno setup: Install MS Loopback adapter with devcon?

Tags: windows, driver, inno-setup

I have read the other answers here about using rundll32 to install drivers, but instructions from Microsoft (admittedly a bit old) at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842561/how-to-install-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter-in-microsoft-windows-ser would have me using a tool named "devcon" to install their loopback adapter from the command line.  Apparently I need to download the entire DDK in order to get a single utility so that I can install one of Microsoft's own devices.

Has anyone tried using devcon from inno setup?  I think it should be fairly straightforward, assuming I can obtain a copy.  Just to be clear, what I want to install is the "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter" -- thanks.

Comment: This is pretty vague question. So try it! And ask only if you have a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need devcon to install driver, you need to use SetupAPI, devcon is just a sample tool that does it. 
you can use [SetupAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi-functions-that-simplify-driver-installation) or [DiFX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff544838(v=vs.96))
for example there is the `DiInstallDriverA` function to install drivers.

Furthermore, you can find the devcon source code in [Microsoft GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon)